# AngularJS and SignalR - difference in defining the app module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

I am trying to integrate my SignalR code with angular. I have followed, maybe, 5 different tutorials but can't get it to work.

[**Following this tutorial**](http://youtu.be/PvGUAsOSL1Q?t=5m27s), where the only difference in my code is that **my app.js** file looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

$(function () {
      $.connection.hub.url = server;
      $.connection.hub.logging = true;

      $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
          console.log('Hub connection open. ID: ' + $.connection.hub.id);
      });
});

angular.module('myApp').value('chat', $.connection.testhub);
```

**and the tutorial app.js looks like this:**

```
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp', [])

  $(function () {
      $.connection.hub.url = server;
      $.connection.hub.logging = true;

      $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
          console.log('Hub connection open. ID: ' + $.connection.hub.id);
      });
   });

  angular.module('myApp').value('chat', $.connection.testhub);
});
```

When accessing the 'chat' service from a controller I can console.log my hub. **But the SignalR logs says that the connection start is taking place before subscribing to a any hub**, so of course no client methods are being called.

**So my question is, is the difference in our app.js files the reason for this issue? And why?**

Everything else is the same and I have verified that the SignalR server works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many different tries without success, I decided to use my ApplicationController(parent of all controllers) as a SignalR handler. From there I can subscribe to all necessary hubs and broadcast events to child scopes to handle the different needs. I'm sure this is not best practices but for my small application it might be enough.

```
myApp.controller('ApplicationController', ['$scope', 'logger', 'AuthService', function ($scope, logger, AuthService) {

$.connection.hub.url = serverUrl;
$.connection.hub.logging = true;

$.connection.testhub.client.getStaff = function (value) {
    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', value);
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log('Hub connection open. ID: ' + $.connection.hub.id);
});

$.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err);
});
}]);
```

So I'll broadcast to send event downstream and emit to send them from child controllers to parent. I think this will do it.

Comment: instead of initializing the SignalR client in the Controller you can use the run(...) method on the AngularJS module (myApp in your case) to start the connection at application startup time (simply replace $scope  by $rootScope). Your controllers then can subscribe to the broadcasted events.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the difference? My ApplicationController is a parent of all other controllers.

Comment: There are two advantages over your approach:
1. You don't "pollute" your controllers with dependencies to an external library. This is not only a better structure of your code base but also is essential if you're writing unit tests. In your controllers you can rely on the AngularJS eventing mechanism and do not need to know about the used library.
2. This doesn't seem to be a case in your current scenario, but when using ng-view and routing, controllers will be destroyed on navigation actions and more important they will be always created newly when navigating back (starting a new connection)

Comment: I understand, thanks. I will look in to your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to queue any requests that are fired before the `done` callback fires.
I have made a abstraction library for SignalR and I solved it like this

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.js#L164

I'm also throttling requests so that they can be sent together if lots of rquests are being fired in sequence

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/blob/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Client.JS/jquery.signalR.eventAggregator.js#L184

You can have a look at the library, it was designed with MVVM in mind and should fit MVC too
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Demo project
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/tree/master/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy.Demo.MVC4

Live demo
http://malmgrens.org/signalR/

Comment: Thanks. I've tried different solutions like that before without success, and was happy when I found a simpler solution(the tutorial). Why does the tutorial work without this queue stuff? I will did into your links and try it again.